# Understanding AWS API Gateway API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have two routes on API Gateway and the behaviour is quite strange. what I'm trying to achieve is send all route with admin/listing including the base routes, like POST admin/listing and also things like PUT admin/listing/archive. ${proxy+} is supposed to capture all routes but it doesn't work for the base routes which is why I have two of them the way it is now but the problem is but when using the ${proxy+}, everything to the left of ${proxy+} is not forwarded to the function

```
/admin/listing
```

This works as expected and the route that's sent to the function comes in the fille form https://url/admin/listing and the router in the function is able to handle it properly

```
/admin/listing/{proxy+}
```

This is where my problem is, the route forwarded to the function is only the route contained in the ${proxy+} so if I went to https://url/admin/listing/archive, the url forwarded to the function is https://url/archive cutting out the admin/listing for some reason but this makes the router in the function unable to handle it since It's expecting admin/listing to be in front of the route.

Has anyone experienced this and have a solution or an alternative method.

Comment: I have been able to figure it out. using gateway v2, I was able to adjust the override the request path